# Laravel Cookie converting forward slash to %2f

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cookies

I am using Laravel 5.6. I am setting a cookie using

```
->cookie('googtrans', '/en/gb', strtotime("+1 year"));
```

however the forward slashes are being converted to %2F giving a value of

```
%2Fen%2Fgb
```

In the middleware for EncryptCookies I exclude the cookie 'googtrans'.

If I use the PHP command

```
setrawcookie('googtrans', '/en/gb', strtotime("+1 year"));
```

everything is OK.

Comment: Cookie just do an url encode that's why slashes converted it to %2F. May i ask what error or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Just use the value of your cookie with `url_decode()` then.

Comment: I don't use it, it is used by Google Translate and because it is in the wrong format, the translate is not working.